# Properties of Harmonic sum sequence

Tags: number-theory

$H_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +...+ \frac{1}{n} = \frac{n_n}{d_n}$ where expression $\frac{n_n}{d_n}$ means irreducible fraction form of $H_n$.

Is there any specific property related with mod operation?
How one calculates $n_n (mod n) , d_n (mod n)$? Is there well defined formula for this kind of calculation?

Answer (score 0):

There are many such results. The one that comes immediately to mind (perhaps because I've assigned it in a number theory class in the past) is [Wolstenholme's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem), which says that the numerator of $H_{p-1}$ is congruent to $0$ mod $p^2$ when $p > 3$ is prime. Or, as none of the denominators are divisible by $p$, it says that
$$
1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{p-1} \equiv 0 \pmod {p^2}.
$$
Like many elementary-seeming number theoretic questions, the methods used to try to understand these sums are many and varied, and also still incomplete.